# Proper ways to refer to New York City

Tags: names, proper-nouns, toponyms

Excluding the myriad nicknames of the city, I've seen it called both "New York City" and "New York" in contexts where it was not ambiguous that the city, and not the state, was being referred to.

I cannot determine if one is the Official™ name either. Wikipedia's page whose URL is `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City` opens with

> New York – often called New York City or the City of New York to distinguish it from the State of New York, of which it is a part ...

A Google search for `"New York"` has a callout to "New York City" on the right side of the page however the mini map shows only "New York." A search for `"New York"` or `"New York City"` in Google Maps both take you to `"New York, NY"` (with the current weather).

The official website of the city is `nyc.gov` but opens with

> The Official Website of the City of New York

Assuming a clear context, is there a difference, even a nuanced one, in meaning between the two?

Comment: Even if there is a clear answer to this, how does it fall within 'English Language and Usage' other than being asked in English?

Comment: I Googled around on the USPS sites.  Could not find anything definitive, but there were numerous uses of "New York, NY" (and "NEW YORK NY") in examples.

Comment: [to New York City](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+new+york+city%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 16,400 hits in Google Books. [to London City](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+london+city%22+-%22city+airport%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), just a couple of hundred (almost all "accidental collocations"). On the other hand, we Brits do sometimes go [to London Town](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+london+town%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#) (or at least, we *used* to, back when it was smaller! :)

Comment: ...and let's not forget [NILSSON - "I Guess The Lord Must Be In New York City"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQRHUp5_tyE). I still love it - haven't got bored *yet!* :)

Comment: I think this is too localized; any answer only relates to the various ways one city, New York City, is known. "New York, NY" is different from "New York, New York." It would be purely a matter of opinion whether the latter encompasses "Staten Island, NY" for example, and while only the former is part of New York County, both are part of the CIty of New York.

Comment: "Old Gotham" sadly seems to be forgotten, with even Batman fans not realising the source of their hero's city's name.

Comment: click to close, no need to comment

Comment: @choster It is very much on topic, it is as localized as discussing any dialect. It is not opinion, but rather _vague_ what the isogloss is for when you call it 'the city', 'New York', or 'New York City' as much as people call it 'soda', 'pop', or 'coke'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the context of London, the word "city" usually refers to the City of London, the financial district.

Comment: @TimLymington I asked it in English Language and Usage because I want to know what the official way to refer to the city is in English and if the two ways I've identified have different meanings in English. Is there a better place to ask the question?

Comment: I edited this question and it was still closed. Did it not go into the review queue? What else can I do to improve the question?

Answer (score 1):

Using the word "City" or the comma and extra New York helps make it clear that you're talking about the city.  It's a good idea to do this to reduce ambiguity in all cases where it's not already quite clear from context (in which case, adding extra words is superfluous without boosting clarity).

Comment: Just to add another level, most people mean Manhattan when they refer to New York City, when Manhattan is, in fact, just one of the 5 boroughs. It's rare when someone is referring to Staten Island when talking about NYC.

Comment: @LaconicDroid Indeed, postal addresses in the other boroughs are Brooklyn, NY etc.

Answer (score 0):

Within a 40 mile radius of Manhattan Island, it is often referred to simply as "The City". So, for example, from that location you would usually say:

"I gotta go in to 'The City'." (meaning Manhattan)

The "go ***in***" part is important - simply, '*go*' would leave a slight ambiguity (as to which nearby city you meant).

Other parts of NYC proper, (other than Manhattan) do not need the '*in'* after 'go', and usually include an expletive:

"I gotta go to %&#@ Staten Island." (or, Brooklyn or, Queens)

"I gotta go to The %&#@ Bronx."  (It is always 'The' Bronx.)